# Getting a list of list of Nearest Neighbour within boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm trying to return a list of list of vertical, horizontal and diagonal nearest neighbors of every item of a 2D numpy array

```py
import numpy as np
import copy
tilemap = np.arange(99).reshape(11, 9)
print(tilemap)

def get_neighbor(pos, array):
    x = copy.deepcopy(pos[0])
    y = copy.deepcopy(pos[1])
    grid = copy.deepcopy(array)
    split = []
    split.append([grid[y-1][x-1]])
    split.append([grid[y-1][x]])
    split.append([grid[y-1][x+1]])
    split.append([grid[y][x - 1]])
    split.append([grid[y][x+1]])
    split.append([grid[y+1][x-1]])
    split.append([grid[y+1][x]])
    split.append([grid[y+1][x+1]])
    print("\n Neighbors of ITEM[{}]\n {}".format(grid[y][x],split))

cordinates = [5, 6]
get_neighbor(pos=cordinates, array=tilemap)
```

i would want a list like this:
`first item = 0`

```
[[1],[12],[13],
 [1,2], [12,24],[13,26],
 [1,2,3], [12,24,36], [13,26,39]....
```

till it get to the boundaries completely then proceeds to `second item = 1`
and keeps adding to the list. if there is a neighbor above it should be add too..

**MY RESULT**

```py
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53]
 [54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62]
 [63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
 [72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80]
 [81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98]]

 Neighbors of ITEM[59]
 [[49], [50], [51], [58], [60], [67], [68], [69]]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this, in what context? This could probably be done (maybe by messing around with strides?), but i’m not optimistic about the performance.

Comment: more of a board game, am trying to get the 8 neighbors in all direction to the boundary of the array when an array index is passed .
@AlexanderCécile i can get the first 8 but getting the `next`, `keeping direction` and `boundary checking` seems to kill me

Comment: You want the 8 neighbours, but broken down like in your post, right? So first the neighbours 1 "cell" away, then 2, etc.

Comment: yes exactly @AlexanderCécile i can only get the first cell only dont know how to get the next.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, what about a using a function like this? This takes the array, your target index, and the "radius" of the elements to be included.

```py
def get_idx_adj(arr, idx, radius):
    num_rows, num_cols = arr.shape
    idx_row, idx_col = idx
    slice_1 = np.s_[max(0, idx_row - radius):min(num_rows, idx_row + radius + 1)]
    slice_2 = np.s_[max(0, idx_col - radius):min(num_cols, idx_col + radius + 1)]
    return arr[slice_1, slice_2]
```

I'm currently trying to find the best way to transform the index of the element, so that the function can be used on its own output successively to get all the subarrays of various sizes.